# If else not read third condition in C

Tags: c

I have a task named ''Discounted Coffee Machine'' with these conditions:

```
if(p<a){
        printf("\nYour balance is not enough.");
        printf("\nRemaining balance: %d",p);
        }
else if(p>=a && dis!=dis2){
        printf("\nEnjoy your Latte. ");
        printf("\nRemaining balance: %d",p-a);
        }
        
else if(p>=a && dis==dis2){
        printf("\nThe discount has been applied.\nEnjoy your Latte.");
        printf("\nRemaining balance: %f",(float)p-(float)a*0.9);
        }
```

But, if I enter the correct discount code, it doesn't read the second else if. It only reads the first else if. How can I solve this?

I tried with the second else if like only else, but it's not working. I also tried with ',' and '||'.

Comment: Best guess -- your discount codes are strings, so you need `strcmp` to compare them -- using `==`/`!=` will compare the addresses of the arrays used to hold them (so will always be `!=`)

Comment: Would be helpful to see this in a [mcve].

Comment: @Phanty, Post the type and vlaues of `dis, dis2`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica
 char dis[]="ostim";
 char dis2[5];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dis` and `dis2` are [character arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74829889/if-else-not-read-third-condition-in-c?noredirect=1#comment132061779_74829889)

```
 char dis[]="ostim"; 
 char dis2[5];
```

`dis!=dis2` compares the addresses of those 2 different arrays and so `dis!=dis2` is always true.  Code needs to compare the *strings* at those addresses.  [@Chris Dodd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74829889/if-else-not-read-third-condition-in-c/74830066#comment132061606_74829889)
Use `strcmp()` which returns 0 when the strings are the same.

Replace `dis!=dis2` with `strcmp(dis, dis2) != 0` or simply

```
// else if(p>=a && dis!=dis2){
else if(p>=a && strcmp(dis, dis2)) {
```

Likewise for `else if(p>=a && dis==dis2)`.

Comment: Also, you don't need p>=a, as if you get past the first 'if', that's guaranteed to be true.

Comment: @user18533375 When `p, a` are floating point types ( a possibility here) `p < a` is not  certainly the opposite of `p>=a`.  Both may be false when a not-a-number is involved.